# Finding centre of mass of frame include 3 rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

Consider the following situation: [image]

I have given that uniform density is $\lambda$ and the lengh of the rods as shown in the picture.

I marked my origin as the bottom of the left corner (and would like to stick with that mark)

I found that total mass is $\frac{5L\lambda}{2}$. I am not sure how I should calculate the second part of the formula, I am having a hard time to express my $\vec{r}$ from the origin.

Comment: It is usually best, if one does not try to solve these kind of question purely mathematically. Instead, try to understand that this is a weighted average. So condense each line to a point and average the three points. Having said this, your question is not a conceptional one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centre of mass (CoM) is always defined with respect to a coordinate system, so choose one carefully, as a good choice will make your calculation much easier. Here the optimum choice will be a Cartesian $xy$ system.

Your  problem is  for a composite mass made up of $n$ elements, each with a known CoM with coordinates $x_i$ and $y_i$ and mass $m_i$.

The CoM coordinates of the composite object are now given by:

$$x_{cm}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1} ^n m_i x_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n m_i}$$

and:

$$y_{cm}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1} ^n m_i y_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n m_i}$$

Of course $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n m_i$ is the total mass of the composite object.

With only $3$ rods, this solves easily. Just choose a coordinate system and work out the $x_i$ and $y_i$. Then calculate!

---

The OP seems to have difficulty determining the CoM of the component parts of the object, so I'll take one example.

[image: Centre of mass]

Take this rod of length $L$ and uniform linear density $\lambda$, placed in a coordinate system as indicated.

Lets deal with $y_{cm}$ of this object first.

Imagine we cut the bar up into an infinite set of very small bars, each with length $\text{d}y$, at position $y$. The mass of each element is of course:

$$\text{d}m=\lambda \text{d}y$$

To find $y_{cm}$ we need to apply a little calculus, by replacing the summations in the formulas above by *integrations*:

$$y_{cm}=\frac{\int_0^L \lambda y\text{d}y}{\int_0^L \lambda \text{d}y}$$

$$y_{cm}=\frac{\frac12 \lambda L^2}{\lambda L}$$

$$\boxed{y_{cm}=\frac{L}{2}}$$

The bar has no mass component in the $x$ direction, so $x_{cm}=0$. The coordinates of the CoM of the bar in the given coordinate system are:

$$\Big(0,\frac{L}{2}\Big)$$

Comment: "Just choose a coordinate system and work out the xi and yi. Then calculate!" This is excatly what I wrote I not understand how to do, I chose my origin on the  left bottom corner and I have no idea how to express $\vec{r}$ from the origin I chose

Comment: Forget about $\vec{r}$ for a minute: that vector needs to be decomposed into $x$ and $y$ components anyway.I'll make an edit to the answer now.

Comment: firstly,thank you for your time I really apreaciate that.
I understand this example because it is simple situation, but what about when I have an angle $\theta$ like I have in the example I added, how If you can guide me the calculate just on rod it will be fine (the fact of the angle is what make it harder for me)

Comment: You need to decompose the angled bars into $x$ and $y$ components, using basic trigonometry ($\times \cos \theta$ and $\times \sin \theta$). Then find the CoM of the decomposed bars.